# How to plot "chainsaw" functions in Maple?

Tags: maple

I want to plot piecewise function. For example,

\begin{cases}
0,  &\ 0\le t<t_1 \\
12e^{-(t-t_1)}, & \ t_1\le t<t_2
\end{cases}

The problem is that function is periodic (let $t_1$=4 and $t_2$=6, period $6$). For one period, it's pretty easy:

```
f := 12*exp(-t+4);
g := 0;
piece := piecewise(0 <= t and t < 4, g, 4 < t and t <= 6, f);
plot(piece, t = 0 .. 6);
```

[image]

But I don't know how to make it periodic. Of course, I can add some new functions in piecewise, but I'm sure that more adequate way to plot periodic fuctions exists. Any help appreciated!

Comment: [Consider](https://tinyurl.com/y72d257n) $\frac6\pi\arctan(\tan(\frac\pi6x+\frac\pi2))+3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to manually copy any part of the original expression into a new operator (manually, eg, cut & paste), to accomplish this. The `unapply` command is useful for that kind of thing.

You started out by giving us this:

```
restart;
f := 12*exp(-t+4):
g := 0:
piece := piecewise(0 <= t and t < 4, g, 4 < t and t <= 6, f):

plot(piece, t = 0 .. 6, size=[200,200]);
```

[image]

Now let's construct an operator from that, which behaves like the supplied `piecewise`, with a period of our choice.

We'll use a re-usable constructor for this purpose.

```
makeperiodic := proc(expr, var, skip)
  local T, r;
  r := skip/2;
  unapply( 'eval'(expr, var=r+'frem'(T+r,skip)), [T], numeric);
end proc:
```

Here is the construction of the periodic operator, and quick check.

```
foo := makeperiodic( piece, t, 6 ):

foo(5);
                      4.414553294

foo(11);
                      4.414553294
```

This operator returns unevaluated when its argument is not numeric, by design.

```
foo(x);
                         foo(x)
```

Now for some plots,

```
# operator form
plot(foo, -12 .. 12, size=[600,200]);
```

[image]

```
# expression form (unevaluated function call)
plot(foo(x), x=-12 .. 12, size=[600,200]);
```

[image]

```
# shift two to the left
plot(foo(x+2), x=-12 .. 12, size=[600,200]);
```

[image]

And we could do a similar thing for some other choice of period,

```
bar := makeperiodic( piece, t, 5 ):
plot(bar, -10 .. 10, size=[500,200]);
plot(bar(t), t=-10 .. 10, size=[500,200]);
# shift 4 to the right
plot(bar(t-4), t=-10 .. 10, size=[500,200]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for new detailed approach to solving this task!

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
 f:=t->12*exp(-t+4)*Heaviside((t-4)*(6-t)):
 s:=t->t-floor(t):
 plot(f(6*s(t/6)),t=0..25);
```

It is easy to modify it with other values of $t_1$ and $t_2$.

[image]

Comment: The function *looks* periodic, but it's not.

Comment: I did, when there was only the hint with the heaviside function, which, being a step function, is totally useless alone to get a periodic one. I am now considering removing it at this answers the question of the plot, with a trick.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Given an interval to be plot, the real periodic function and mine can be made the same.

Comment: Yes, that's why I removed the downvote. But notice it now all depends on the reange of the plot (can be adapted with a varying upper bound in the sum, but this is way too tricky to my taste). While there is a simple way to make the function mathematically periodic.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I see your point and I edited my answer. Do you like it now?

Comment: @Robert Z, thank you for the answer, +1. Is your idea appliable to any piecewise periodic function or to this particular only? It seems to me that Heaviside step function can be used only if one of "pieces" is zero. Does a way to plot any periodic piecewise function exists?

Comment: @KellyShepphard Yes we can generalize to more pieces. For each piece you use a Heaviside step function and then you add together all the pieces.

Comment: @Robert Z, so the basic algorithm is to make for each function first two lines of code, and then plot f1+f2+f3...? If you don't mind, could you explain (or give a link), please, how to use these lines for any function?

Comment: if you have two pieces $f1$ on $[a,b]$ and $f2$ on $[c,d]$ then 
f=f1*Heaviside((x-a)(b-x))+f2*Heaviside((x-c)(d-x)). Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. And both "6" in "plot" are for period given?

Comment: Yes, that is the period.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I get it now. :)